# Flot.js Circle Data points render as square

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm using Flot.js to make a simple line chart on my page; the problem I'm currently faced is that, without any clear cause, the data points which I've chosen to render as circles will occasionally render as squares. Most of the time, it appears normally. However, occasionally after a refresh of the page the chart will simply decide to appear differently. It's unclear what the cause of this is.

One thing which I've noticed however is that, when this bug occurs, another chart I have (this one a pie chart) stops properly rendering the radial hole in the center. One always occurs at the same time as the other; resizing the chart area (using the resize plugin) doesn't help and refreshing causes it to display properly only some of the time.

Here's a list of plugins I'm loading:

- Flot core
- Navigate
- Pie charts
- Resize
- Selection
- Threshold
- Time

Note that not all of these are used for all of the charts; navigate, selection, threshold, and time are all used only for the line chart, and resize is used for everything.

Comment: You need to provide a jsFiddle that attempts to recreate the bug, or at the very least some source code that creates the bug.  The way your question is written now is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: Which source code, specifically? The only things I can really give are my chart options and the graph data; nothing else has been modified from the basic Flot libraries.

Comment: It seems like you have a pretty complicated setup.  Without giving us some sort of code which replicates that setup, you are asking us to either 1.) guess at what the problem might be or 2.) take our time to recreate your setup, so we can debug it for you.  Neither alternative is conducive for you getting an answer.

Comment: Yeah, probably true. The problem is that recreating the bug is hard, because its happening doesn't seem linked to any event or course of action. The fact that it displays normally 90% of the time, and that there's no in-app trigger which causes this--in fact, it traditionally happens on page load--makes me suspect it's a Flot-specific issue.

Comment: One thing I can suggest, off the top of my head, is to make sure all your plot creation calls are wrapped in a `.ready()` event and you are not in-lining javascript.

Comment: I make sure not to fire any events before the template rendering is complete and ready to go; when I don't that causes Flot to fail completely as the canvas element has no set size. Additionally, I'm careful to use the :visible jQuery selector when initially calling Flot on an element to ensure that the chart is only rendered if the element can actually be seen and exists, for safety reasons.